# Camel exec component - parameters couldn't be set on the endpoint

Tags: windows, apache-camel

Below is the code for my camel exec component. This is one of my first times using Camel and I'm just trying to get camel exec to execute a batch file for me. Can anyone tell me how I misconfigured the workingDir parameter? As part of the error I am getting that 1 parameters couldn't be set. If it matters I'm working on windows.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

/**
 * A Camel Java DSL Router
 */
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:exec").to("exec:mybat.bat?workingDir=C:/Users/userName/Desktop");
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you pls post the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EgoKilla, below is the working code

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("timer:foo?period=5000").to("exec:D:/jboss/test.bat?");
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

Here for every 5000 msec, camel executes the batch file. I give the fully qualified path of the bat file.

Working directory means, the directory which the command should be executed. ex: if you trying to create a file using batch file, that file will be created in the working directory specified.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: How do I adjust this so my executable only runs once?

Comment: You can use camel quartz scheduler. Using cron expression you can control that. There are many online website where you can form a cron expression. You can trigger daily; weekly; monthly; basis.